# How to program std::bitset<VariableValue>

Tags: c++, oop, bitset

I am willing to have a bitset which has it size changing depending on the instance of my class `Foo`.
Each instance depends on an integer `n` and I want to create a bitset which has the minimal number of bits used to create a bits word when I convert the decimal integer to binary.

But for each instance it could change thus I want to have my bitset size as a variable of my integer.

I wrote this code, but it not working that way. Do you have any hint for me please ?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int value);
    int numberOfBits(int value);
    std::bitset<_numberOfBits> decToBinary(int value); // Size of bitset depending on the instance
    int getValue();
    void setValue(int value);
    int getNumberOfBits();
    void setNumberOfBits(int numberOfBits);
private:
    int _value;
    int _numberOfBits;
};

Foo::Foo(int value)
{   
    setValue(value);
    setNumberOfBits(value);
}
int Foo::numberOfBits(int value)
{
    return(ceil(log2(value + 1)));
}
int Foo::getValue()
{
    return _value;
}
void Foo::setValue(int value)
{
    _value = value;
}
int Foo::getNumberOfBits()
{
    return _numberOfBits;
}
void Foo::setNumberOfBits(int numberOfBits)
{
    _numberOfBits = numberOfBits;
}
std::bitset<_numberOfBits> Foo::decToBinary(int value)
{
    return(std::bitset<_numberOfBits>(value));
}
```

Comment: `std::bitset` doesn't support this. Template arguments are always evaluated at compile time. You can try `std::vector<bool>` which, for better or worse, is required to pack bools to 1 bit each.

Comment: However, If `n` has an upper bound smaller than `sizeof(std::vector<bool>) * CHAR_BIT` 
 (320 on my system), you would be better off just using a `std::bitset<upper_bound>` and ignore the unused bits. (the actual worthwhile threshold is probably higher still)

Comment: @Frank I have the `upper_bound` but it is calculated using `n`.
For example using `n = 2047`, I calcultate length of word of `11` and then I want a bitset of size 11.

Comment: @yacth By "upper bound" I mean, the largest value  for `_numberOfBits` that your program can possibly encounter, if it's based on `n` and `n` is an integer, then your upper bound is 64. Much smaller than the 320 threshold on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @Frank Sorry my bad, I meant "having its binary representation" because it is easier to see it as a binary when I want to do bitwise operation on it.

Comment: @yacth You can do bitwise manipulation on `int`s just fine. Using a bitset  here is jumping through a bunch of hoops for no good reason.

Comment: @Frank In that case my `upper_bound` is `2^19` since I am working on words with a maximum lenght of `19`. But  I can store more than one word in these 19 bits allocated for my data, thus using the whole 19 bits with `0` for the unused bits could complicate everything.

Comment: @Frank To be more precise, I am working on ARINC429. And there is a part where I need 2's complement, that is why I wanted to use `std::bitset` to have a troncation on the useless `1` and be able to manipulate easily my data.

Comment: If you bound is `2^19`, then define 19 distinct `bitset` instances, and code yourself a builder that will return the right one based on your `n`.

Comment: @jxh I didn't find a way to concatenate these bitsets afterwards because I need to concatenate a whole word to send it to my hardware. 
I found another way but it is not theoritically correct, let's say I have a negative encoded number on 19 bits but the data takes 7 bits and the sign is the 8th bit. Then I reset all the bits from 19 to 9, it works but I don't know yet about the efficiency.

Comment: @yacth Your requirements are not well specified. If you never need more than 19 bits, just use a 32 bit unsigned number to represent your set.

Comment: @jxh Ok my bad let me get more specific. I am using ARINC429 words they are coded on 32 bits, but not all the bits are used to encode the data. the bits from 11 to 29 are used to encode the data (the 19 bits I am willing to set). I am facing a problem I am trying to solve here, I can store more than one value in the 19 bits allocated for the data. I can store a value from 11 to 13 and another value from 14 to 29, that is why I was willing to look for a way to have a dynamic bitset.

Comment: @yacth It is not clear what using `bitset` gains you that you would not be able to achieve with a 32 bit unsigned integer. Using an unsigned integer would mean you would eliminate bits by masking. And the mask can be generated dynamically easily.

Comment: @jxh I am still new using C++, I looked on the internet and I found the bitset library. If you tell me that it works with an unsigned integer I am willing to give it a shot. But I don't really know how to manipulate that knowing that my 32bits word is divded in 5 parts as shown here https://www.ueidaq.com/uploads/arinc-429-word-format.jpg

Comment: @yacth Only wanting the bottom 19 bits: `(0x7FFFF & x)`. Only wanting bits 11 to 29: `((0x7FFFF << 11) & x)`.